# Can't get UItextfield to accept floating point in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield, floating

I'm trying to get my UItextField to accept floating point but at the moment, it will only accept an integer.  How can I get it to accept floating point in Swift?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Swallow13Button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func Swallow13Button (sender: AnyObject) {

            let a:Int? = data1.text.toInt()

            if a > 13.13 {


                self.DimensionLabel.text = "Fail Send DWG For Review"

                self.view.endEditing(true)

            }    

            else {


                self.DimensionLabel.text = "Pass Send DWG for Review"

                self.view.endEditing(true) 
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert using `NSString`'s `floatValue`:

```
let a: Float = (data1.text as NSString).floatValue
```

Comment: @Armin, `floatValue` returns a `Float` not an Optional type, so `a` should be of type `Float`. If the string is not valid it will return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to float like this

```
let a = (data1 as NSString).floatValue
```